# Nextjs nested routing not working with a file

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes

I'm facing a problem creating routes in Nextjs;
When creating the directory "/app/[locale]/admin/page.tsx; I can access http://url/admin/

But when creating "/app/[locale]/admin/login.tsx; I can't access http://url/admin/login

Only if I create "/app/[locale]/admin/login/page.tsx; I can access http://url/admin/login

But I wouldn't want to have this mess of directories in my project.

Can you help me with this solution?

/app/[locale]/admin/login.tsx:

```
import '../globals.scss'
import React from "react";

export default function Login() {

    return (
        <>
            Code
        </>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax issue here, as all the files should have a standard that Next.js understand, in your case is that you are naming the file with the name of the function that represents. That is not good as next doesn't understand the routing like that. Nextjs will search for the "page.tsx or jsx" in the route that correspond with the folder organization.

/app/[locale]/admin/random.tsx it will not show anything
/app/[locale]/admin/login/random.tsx it will not show anything
/app/[locale]/admin/login/page.tsx it will show the component inside page in that particular route.

page.tsx will represent the name of the folder its in.
In the first case: "/app/[locale]/admin/login.tsx" for this to work you should change the "login.tsx" to "page.tsx".